# Using Excel, how to compare two plans (line has same code but different number of characters)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two plans in Excel: both have the columns 'code' and 'name'. I want to display in plan3 the rows from plan1 whose name column has a different number of characters from name column from plan2 (code column is the primary key). I'd like to use Excel formulas to do that.

[image]
Using the answer suggested, I finally solved the problem: in brazilian Excel, the formula is:
 `=NÚM.CARACT(PROCV(A2;Plan1!A:B;2;0))<>NÚM.CARACT(PROCV(A2;Plan2!A:B;2;0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, where G2 etc is your plan3 'code':

```
=LEN(VLOOKUP(G2,plan1,2,0))<>LEN(VLOOKUP(G2,plan2,2,0))
```

copied down to suit, where 'TRUE' indicates the string lengths are not equal and `plan1` and `plan2` are named ranges.

Where `plan1` and `plan2` are not named ranges but sheet names and layout is as in image, please try:

```
=LEN(VLOOKUP(A2,plan1!A:B,2,0))<>LEN(VLOOKUP(A2,plan2!A:B,2,0))
```

for example:

[image: SO21676735 example]

Filter ColumnB of plan3 to select TRUE for those that do not match. ColumnA of pla3 should be a comprehensive list. The ordering does not matter.

Comment: I didn't understand G2... Should I copy the column code from Plan1 on G column from Plan3?

Comment: Do you know if VLOOKUP is equivalent to PROCV in brazilian version of Excel?

Comment: Yes, actually plan1 is sheet1... any changes in the formula above?

Comment: I put the image of the situation.